# Rare but persistent recv() error due to socket operation on non-socket in my multi-client TCP server code

Tags: c, sockets, select, recv

I have a TCP server & UDP server, on the same port, who are serving multiple clients by using the select() function. Normally, everything is fine & clients can communicate with both servers, but sometimes, on rare occasions, I get error message which is due to recv() error socket operation on non-socket. If I print the socket descriptor in such situations, it is mostly 1(stdout) or 0(stdin). So it should throw up that error but why does my code tries to recv() from those sockets in the first place is my question.

Here is my code snippet
1. TCP Socket creation

```
// TCP port setup
    int sockfd; // listening socket descriptor
    int newsockfd; // newly accept()ed socket descriptor
    struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen;

    char buf_tcp[256]; // buffer for client data
    char buf_copy_tcp[256];    
    int recv_bytes;

    char remoteIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    int yes=1; // for setsockopt() SO_REUSEADDR
    int i, k, rv_getaddrinfo, rv_setsockopt, rv_bind, rv_listen, rv_select;

    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *ptr;

    // get a socket and bind it
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    rv_getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo);
    if (rv_getaddrinfo != 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "CLI Server TCP error: %s\r\n", gai_strerror(rv_getaddrinfo));
        exit(1);
    }

    for(ptr=servinfo; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->ai_next) 
    {
        sockfd = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (sockfd == -1)  
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP error: socket\r\n");
            continue;
        }

        // lose the pesky "address already in use" error message
        rv_setsockopt = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));
        if(rv_setsockopt == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP error: setsockopt\r\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        rv_bind = bind(sockfd, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (rv_bind == -1) 
        {
            close(sockfd);
            fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP error: bind\r\n");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    // if we got here, it means we didn't get bound
    if (ptr == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP error: failed to bind\r\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this

    // listen
    rv_listen = listen(sockfd, 10);
    if (rv_listen == -1) 
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP error: listen\r\n");
        exit(3);
    }
```

2. UDP Socket creation

```
// UDP port setup
    int sockfd_udp; // listening socket descriptor
    struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr_udp; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen_udp;

    char buf_udp[256]; // buffer for client data
    char buf_copy_udp[256];    
    int recv_bytes_udp;

    char remoteIP_udp[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    int yes_udp=1; // for setsockopt() SO_REUSEADDR
    int j, rv_getaddrinfo_udp, rv_setsockopt_udp, rv_bind_udp;

    struct addrinfo hints_udp, *servinfo_udp, *ptr_udp;

    // get a socket and bind it
    memset(&hints_udp, 0, sizeof(hints_udp));
    hints_udp.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints_udp.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints_udp.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    rv_getaddrinfo_udp = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints_udp, &servinfo_udp);
    if (rv_getaddrinfo_udp != 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "CLI Server UDP error: %s\r\n", gai_strerror(rv_getaddrinfo_udp));
        exit(1);
    }

    for(ptr_udp=servinfo_udp; ptr_udp!=NULL; ptr_udp=ptr_udp->ai_next) 
    {
        sockfd_udp = socket(ptr_udp->ai_family, ptr_udp->ai_socktype, ptr_udp->ai_protocol);
        if (sockfd_udp == -1)  
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server UDP error: socket\r\n");
            continue;
        }

        // lose the pesky "address already in use" error message
        rv_setsockopt_udp = setsockopt(sockfd_udp, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes_udp, sizeof(int));
        if(rv_setsockopt_udp == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server UDP error: setsockopt\r\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        rv_bind_udp = bind(sockfd_udp, ptr_udp->ai_addr, ptr_udp->ai_addrlen);
        if (rv_bind_udp == -1) 
        {
            close(sockfd_udp);
            fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server UDP error: bind\r\n");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    // if we got here, it means we didn't get bound
    if (ptr_udp == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server UDP error: failed to bind\r\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo_udp); // all done with this
```

3. select() function for multi-client server

```
struct timeval timeout; // timeout for select(), 1ms
timeout.tv_sec  = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 1000;
fd_set master; // master file descriptor list
fd_set read_fds; // temp file descriptor list for select()
int fdmax; // maximum file descriptor number  

FD_ZERO(&master); // clear the master and temp sets
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);

// add the listener to the master set
FD_SET(sockfd, &master);
FD_SET(sockfd_udp, &master);

// keep track of the biggest file descriptor
if(sockfd > sockfd_udp)
    fdmax = sockfd; // so far, it's this one
else
    fdmax = sockfd_udp; // so far, it's this one  

while(1)
{
    read_fds = master; // copy it

    rv_select = select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (rv_select == -1) 
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP error: select\r\n");
        exit(4);
    }

    // run through the existing connections looking for data to read
    for(i=0; i<=fdmax; i++) 
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) 
        { // we got one!!
            if (i == sockfd) 
            {
                // handle new tcp connections
                addrlen = sizeof(remoteaddr);
                newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr, &addrlen);

                if (newsockfd == -1) 
                    fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP error: accept\r\n");
                else 
                {
                    FD_SET(newsockfd, &master); // add to master set
                    if (newsockfd > fdmax)      // keep track of the max
                        fdmax = newsockfd;

                    inet_ntop(remoteaddr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr), remoteIP, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
                    fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP: new connection from %s on socket %d\r\n", remoteIP, newsockfd);
                }
            } 
            else if (i == sockfd_udp) 
            {
                // handle new udp connections
                addrlen_udp = sizeof(remoteaddr_udp);
                if ((recv_bytes_udp = recvfrom(i, buf_udp, sizeof(buf_udp), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr_udp, &addrlen_udp)) < 0) 
                    fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server UDP error: recvfrom\r\n");
                else 
                {   // handle data from a client
                    inet_ntop(remoteaddr_udp.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr_udp), remoteIP_udp, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
                    for(j=0; j<=recv_bytes_udp; j++)
                    {
                        if( (buf_udp[j] == '\r') | (buf_udp[j] == '\n') )
                            buf_udp[j] = '\0';
                    }
                    fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server UDP: received %s from connection %s\r\n", buf_udp, remoteIP_udp);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {   // handle data from a client
                if ((recv_bytes = recv(i, buf_tcp, sizeof(buf_tcp), 0)) <= 0) 
                {   // got error or connection closed by client
                    if (recv_bytes == 0) // connection closed
                        fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP: socket %d hung up\r\n", i);
                    else 
                        fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP error: recv from socket %d\r\n", i);

                    if(i > sockfd_udp) // temporary fix as recv error occurs on any open file descriptors.  
                        close(i); // bye!

                    FD_CLR(i, &master); // remove from master set
                } 
                else 
                {
                    for(k=0; k<=recv_bytes; k++)
                    {
                        if( (buf_tcp[k] == '\r') | (buf_tcp[k] == '\n') )
                            buf_tcp[k] = '\0';
                    }
                    fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP: received %s from socket %d\r\n", buf_tcp, i);
                }
            } // END handle data from client
        } // END got new incoming connection
    } // END looping through file descriptors

    usleep(2000);
}
```

After the select() call, I run through all socket descriptors in a for loop. But the if(FD_ISSET()) condition should weed out non-sockets like 0, 1 etc. The only place where FD_SET() is used in the while(1) loop is to accept() new TCP clients, those socket descriptors must be > TCP socket descriptor so there is no chance that 0(stdin), 1(stdout) are getting set in the master set. But somehow they do. Why does my code think it should recv() from non-sockets & then generate that error. Who is setting descriptors 0 & 1 in my master set of select().

This error is rare but persistent. In my earlier version of the code, when I get the error, i close() that socket descriptor. So I was closing stdin, stdout & some other file descriptors(which I had created using open()). This was messing up my code so to mask the above issue I used the if(i > sockfd_udp) to close() descriptor, so that only client socket descriptors(through accept()) are closed.

Can anyone identify the issue?

Comment: regarding: `rv_select = select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);`   Must also check for `rv_select` being 0 (I.E. a timeout occurred)

Comment: regarding: `usleep(2000);`  this statement is not needed.

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server TCP error: recv from socket %d\r\n", i);`   Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  and should include the reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest inserting: `perror( "recv failed" ); before the call to `fprintf()`

Comment: on linux (and probably other OSs) the values in the `timeout` struct are modified each time `select()` executes, so should be 'refreshed' before each call to `select()`

Comment: must not close() any socket number (0, 1, ... are all valid socket numbers) lower than the 'socket_TCP'  that is not set via a call to FD_SET().  The call to `accept()` will use the lowest numbered socket number that is available.  Infact, 'select()' should not react to any socket number that is not 'set' via a call to `FD_SET()`

Comment: @user3629249 select() function modifies the file descriptor set that is passed to it. So should I use FD_ISSET(i, &master) instead of FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds) in the if() condition following the for() loop?

Comment: No, do not check `master`,  check the `fd_set` that was used in the call to `select()`